# Can a debit card reader be used in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, hardware

For online banking/accounting you need a debit card reader,
like for example an *e.dentifier* from ABN AMRO (bank in Holland).

They told me this e.dentifier debit card reader is plug and play
on Windows, so nothing extra to be installed, just plug it in,
and in the browser you can pay directly using the reader, your
debit card and transfer $ to a online store for a purchase.
It also seems to work the same way on MacOS, what they told me,
(Customer Service).

However when I asked them about Linux (Ubuntu/Xubuntu) support, they could not even answer my question.
The customer service of the bank does not even know if the
reader would work on Linux; they told me they are unaware if
someone has made drivers for it or if they were needed at all.

Now I'm in real doubt, I don't have a debitcard reader
(e.dentifier) to try this out, but what is the case here?
Do these readers work out-of-the-box on Linux also, and is
this just something which is going via the browser, or is
something more needed? They told me no extra software had to
be installed for Windows/MacOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unconnected method. That one works regardless of operating system. I have been using one with Linux + Firefox and Chromium for years now.

[abn amro](https://www.abnamro.nl/nl/images/Generiek/PDFs/Overig/edentifier2_usermanual_english.pdf)

> Two methods of use: connected and unconnected With an unconnected e.dentifier2 you can use our digital services wherever you want. With the e.dentifier2 connected to your PC by the USB cable, things are even easier. To log on, all you have to do is enter a PIN. combined with a check of your account and card number. Connected use requires one-off installation of software

The one using USB needs investigating: plug it in and type `lsusb`. It will show a list of connected devices. I doubt it will work though without adjusting something: a browser in Ubuntu does not have access to usb devices. According to this [Dutch link to ABN AMRO](https://www.abnamro.nl/nl/zakelijk/producten/digitaal-bankieren/mkb/internetbankieren/mogelijkheden/systeemeisen-en-browsers.html): Linux, Opera, and older Windows are NOT supported using the connected method.

Comment: yes is see it. they seem to only support windows vista/7/8/10 and macos. * ! well i guess i have to live with this then. doesnt matter anyway, the bank is only a 15 mins walk from where i live, and they offer this service there as well, for in case i ever need it.

Comment: The only difference with the not-wired: you need to type in your PIN code when connecting. Not a very big deal to me :)   Mind that it ALSO allows logging in using a QR code they provide so install the abn app. I use that more than the e-identifier to be honest :D